# Background image has a 1px border in Firefox (and only Firefox!)

Tags: css, firefox

Slightly baffled by this one - I'm working on a [tiny static site](http://emmawinston.github.io/enderbys-room-new/index.html) with a large background image, which is rendering with a 1px black top border in Firefox. There's no border in the image and it doesn't render in any other browser. I haven't managed to find any references to this happening with a background image anywhere and am not quite sure how to fix it!

[image: Screenshot of the offending border.]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Looks fine for me in firefox.

Comment: Seems to be caused when the `-20%` value in `background-position: center -20%;` computes to a non-pixel-aligned value. I don't see the line at all sizes, and using a pixel value instead of a percentage makes it disappear. As for why this happens, IDK, so +1.

Comment: Added a screenshot. I'll see if I can make it work with fixed pixel values instead!

Comment: Have you modified your CSS since posting this question? If not, which version of Firefox are you using? I'm not seeing it here either, despite what Alexander O'Mara has said.

Comment: I haven't modified it yet, no. I'm running 34.0 on OS X Yosemite and still seeing it intermittently, though I'm not always able to reproduce it consistently, oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in the latest build of Firefox (not sure whether to post this as an answer to my own question or as part of the question?)

Answer (score -3):

You should make sure you have resets for all css, like normalize.css. This way all browsers act the same.

img { border:0; }

Comment: The image is provided in the CSS as a background image, not in an `<img>` element.

Comment: Just as a heads-up - normalize.css is already there in the head of my source code and has been since before I posted this question so I don't think it's a reset issue! Also, as misterManSam points out, it's not an img element.